# custom inspector CSS copied to stylesheet not being applied on refresh

Tags: css

I'm using Edge Inspector to build a CSS class, like:

```
.blurbs .et_pb_button_module_wrapper {background-color: white; padding: 2em;}
```

I see these attributes being applied on the page.

If I copy this CSS rule and save it into the WP child theme CSS, I can see the rule is there when I load the stylesheet in the browser.

However, the rule is not being applied on the page.

It is not even present when I select the `.blurbs .et_pb_button_module_wrapper` element, so although it might be overridden if it was present, there's nothing to override.

```html
<link href="https://divi.dev.insightdesign.com.au/agrimin/wp-content/themes/Divi-Agrimin/style.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://divi.dev.insightdesign.com.au/agrimin/wp-content/themes/Divi/style.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="et_pb_row et_pb_row_0 blurbs et_pb_equal_columns">
<div class="et_pb_column et_pb_column_1_3 et_pb_column_0 et_pb_section_parallax  et_pb_css_mix_blend_mode_passthrough"> <span class="et_parallax_bg_wrap"><span class="et_parallax_bg" style="background-image: url(&quot;http://divi.dev.insightdesign.com.au/agrimin/wp-content/uploads/sites/20/2020/11/green-card-01.jpg&quot;); height: 567.3px; transform: translate(0px, 177.53px);"></span></span>
<div class="et_pb_module et_pb_blurb et_pb_blurb_0  et_pb_text_align_left  et_pb_blurb_position_top et_pb_bg_layout_light">
  <div class="et_pb_blurb_content">
    <div class="et_pb_main_blurb_image"><span class="et_pb_image_wrap"><img loading="lazy" width="39" height="36" src="http://divi.dev.insightdesign.com.au/agrimin/wp-content/uploads/sites/20/2020/11/icon-5.png" alt="" class="et-waypoint et_pb_animation_top wp-image-274 et-animated"></span></div>
    <div class="et_pb_blurb_container">
      <h4 class="et_pb_module_header"><span>Information For</span></h4>
      <div class="et_pb_blurb_description">
        <h3><span style="color: #008000;">Company&nbsp;</span><br>
          <span style="color: #008000;">Overview</span></h3>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- .et_pb_blurb_content --> 
</div>
<!-- .et_pb_blurb -->
<div class="et_pb_button_module_wrapper et_pb_button_0_wrapper et_pb_button_alignment_left et_pb_module "> <a class="et_pb_button et_pb_button_0 et_pb_bg_layout_dark" href="">More</a> </div>
  </div>
  <!-- .et_pb_column -->
  <div class="et_pb_column et_pb_column_1_3 et_pb_column_1 et_pb_section_parallax  et_pb_css_mix_blend_mode_passthrough et_pb_column_empty"> <span class="et_parallax_bg_wrap"><span class="et_parallax_bg" style="background-image: url(&quot;http://divi.dev.insightdesign.com.au/agrimin/wp-content/uploads/sites/20/2020/11/green-card-02.jpg&quot;); height: 567.3px; transform: translate(0px, 177.53px);"></span></span> </div>
  <!-- .et_pb_column -->
  <div class="et_pb_column et_pb_column_1_3 et_pb_column_2 et_pb_section_parallax  et_pb_css_mix_blend_mode_passthrough et-last-child et_pb_column_empty"> <span class="et_parallax_bg_wrap"><span class="et_parallax_bg" style="background-image: url(&quot;http://divi.dev.insightdesign.com.au/agrimin/wp-content/uploads/sites/20/2020/11/green-card-03.jpg&quot;); height: 567.3px; transform: translate(0px, 177.53px);"></span></span> </div>
  <!-- .et_pb_column --> 
  </div>
```

The element that needs the white background the container of the `More` button: `.blurbs .et_pb_button_module_wrapper`

Help appreciated.

Comment: Considering that it works absolutely fine here, when I copy&paste your snippet to an answer, and then just apply that single line of CSS you have shown via the CSS editor input box, I’d say you have not presented enough information to make this problem reproducible. What have _you_ done to try and debug this so far then? Have you at least inspected the element in your browser dev tools, and checked if any more specific rules might apply, that have overwritten the properties you tried to set?

Comment: @CBroe added to Q: `It is not even present when I select the .blurbs .et_pb_button_module_wrapper element, so although it might be overridden if it was present, there's nothing to override`